# Access returnValue from another class

Tags: java, return-value

I want to access a return Value from another .Class. Do i rly have to make it static?

For example:

Class 1 Called Player

```
public int getRemainingItemUses(){
    return remainingItemUses;
}
```

Class 2

```
Player.getRemainingItemUses()
```

My Error is Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getRemainingItemUses() from the type Player

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either make `getRemainingItemUses()` static, or create an instance of `Class1` and invoke the method on it:

```
Class1 c = new Class1();
int result = c.getRemainingItemUses();
```